# how to make a script recognize number which are the same in python 3.3

Tags: numbers, python-3.3

I wont this to be able to see if 2 or more number are the same and then add them to a list.
That's the best way i can describe what i wont to do.

```
 deck=["3","1","3","3"]
 print(deck)
if deck[0]==deck[1]:
  global thesame
  thesame=[deck[0],deck[1]]
else:
 if deck[0]==deck[2]:
    thesame=[deck[0],deck[2]]
 else:
    if deck[0]==deck[3]:
            thesame=[deck[0],deck[3]]
    else:
        if deck[0]==deck[1]and deck[0] ==  deck[2]:
            thesame=[deck[0],deck[1],deck[2]]
        else:
            if deck[0]==deck[1]and deck[0] ==   deck[3]:
                thesame=[deck[0],deck[1],deck[3]]
            else:
                if deck[0]==deck[2] and deck[0] == deck[3]:
                    thesame=[deck[0],deck[1],deck[2]]

 print(thesame)
```

Any help would be appreciated !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code tests only if a number is the same as the first.

```
the_same = []
for i in deck[1:]:
    if i == deck[0]:
        the_same.append(i)
```

If you want to test if any number is duplicated, you can use a Counter.

```
from collections import Counter
counter = Counter(deck)
the_same = []
for i in counter:
    if counter[i] > 1:
        the_same.extend([i] * counter[i])
```